# nodemailer online.net 550-HELO can't be [127.0.0.1]. Please contact your ISP

Tags: smtp, nodemailer, chilkat-email

I have a problem on sending mails online.net with nodemailer.
While it works fine with chilkat's mailman module (node.js) on the same environment

nodemailer version

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtpauth.online.net",
  port: 587,
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    user: "xxx@domain.fr",
    pass: "xxx",
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
  },
});

transporter
  .sendMail({
    from: "xxx@domain.fr",
    to: "true@eadress.fr",
    subject: "Test online",
    text: "Test online"
  })
  .then((info) => {
    console.log("Preview URL: " + nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

chilkat-version

```
var mailman = new chilkat.MailMan();
    mailman.SmtpHost = "smtpauth.online.net";
    mailman.SmtpUsername = "xxx@domain.fr";
    mailman.SmtpPassword = "xxx";

    mailman.SmtpSsl = false;
    mailman.StartTLS = true;
    mailman.SmtpPort = 587;

    var email = new chilkat.Email();

    email.Subject = "Test online";
    email.Body = "Test online";
    email.From = "xxx@domain.fr";
    var success = email.AddTo("Bob","true@eadress.fr");

    success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
    if (success !== true) {
        console.log(mailman.LastErrorText);
        return;
    }

    success = mailman.CloseSmtpConnection();
    if (success !== true) {
        console.log("Connection to SMTP server not closed cleanly.");
    }

    console.log("Mail Sent!");
```

Following the scaleway doc (https://www.scaleway.com/en/docs/webhosting/classic/how-to/check-emails/), I tried all ports (25, 465, 587, 2525 ). I changed the host from smtpauth.online.net to smtp.online.net, nothing helped.

If anyone has solved this problem that would be a great help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

it works by adding "name" option in createTransport

> name – optional hostname of the client, used for identifying to the server, defaults to hostname of the machine

```
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: 'www.domain.com',
    host: "smtpauth.online.net",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth: {
      user: "xxx@domain.fr",
      pass: "xxx",
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });
```